# How to handle exception in Julia

Tags: exception, julia

I want to handle a exception in Julia Lang, just like I did with Javascript:

```
try {

} catch(e) {
     console.log("Exception: " + e);
}
```

I read the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/control-flow/#Exception-Handling-1) but I'm not able to understand.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The equivalent to your code is:

```
try
    sqrt(-1) # Code that may throw an exception.
catch y
    warn("Exception: ", y) # What to do on error.
end
```

The full structure of `try`/`catch` statement is:

```
try
    # Code that may throw an error.
[catch [identifier]
    # What to do if exception is raised.
]
[finally
    # What to do unconditionally when try/catch block exits.
]
end
```

Parts in square brackets are optional. In particular if you want to omit `identifier` you should use a newline or `;` after `catch`.